# Why can I not use an inline function for a Screen component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

In the getting started of the React-Navigation documentation they say:

> Note: The component prop accepts component, not a render function. Don't pass an inline function (e.g. component={() => }), or your component will unmount and remount losing all state when the parent component re-renders. See Passing additional props for alternatives.

From my understanding if I write:

```
const WrappedHome = () => <HomeScreen />;
```

Then later use this:

```
<Stack.Screen name='home' component={WrappedHome} />
```

That would be equivilent to their example. Is React or JSX or React-native doing something special to cause inline function in props to be evaluated differently than standard Javascript? Or what am i misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A component is not just a regular function. When you render a component, it has a "type" - which is the function that creates the component:

e.g:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  // whatever
}

<MyComponent /> // the component type is MyComponent
```

Whenever a re-render happens, React looks at this type. If it's the same, then it'll keep the component's state, and re-render it.

Now let's say you render `MyComponent` during first render, but then changed it to `OtherComponent` later. React will unmount `MyComponent` and render `OtherComponent`. All the local state of `MyComponent` will be destroyed when it unmounts.

When you create components inline inside another component, every render, there's a new function created, which means a new component type every render. Since the type changes every render, React will unmount previous component and mount the new component every time, which is undesirable.

Take the following example:

```js
const a = { foo: 42 };

function getA() {
  return a;
}

getA() === getA(); // the returned `a` is always the same because you defined the object outside `getA`

function getB() {
  return { foo: 42 };
}

getB() !== getB(); // the returned object is a new one every time you call `getB` because you defined the object inside `getB`
```

So it's not that inline functions are evaluated differently, the problem is because every time there's a new component which destroys any local state and even if you don't have local state, unmounting a component and mounting a new one is usually slower than updating the same component.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is redefining the expression.

If I set the component in a function, like `function getA() {}`, but it was inside the function, I would still get a new `getA` each call, and it would be equivilent to doing it inline. Each function call would give a new `getA`, which would lose state, etc. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, the component has to be defined outside of the render function for the navigator. That's the key.